# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined [json ,ajax y DataTables]

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, datatables

No consigo mostrar los datos en mi tabla.

Con el siguiente index envío por json los datos de mi tabla:

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $modelos = Modelos::all();
        return response()->json($modelos);
    }
    return view('modelos.index');
}
```

Luego en mi vista cuando lo intento mostrar:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#mytable').DataTable( {
            "ajax": "/modelo",
            "columns": [
                { "data": "marca" },
                { "data": "modelo" },
                { "data": "part_number" },
                { "data": "coste" },
                { "data": "caracteristicas" },
            ]
        } );

 <body>
<a href="{!!URL::to('/modelo/create')!!}" class="create">Nuevo</a>
<table id="mytable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Marca</th>
            <th>Modelo</th>
            <th>Part Number</th>
            <th>Coste</th>
            <th>Características</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Marca</th>
            <th>Modelo</th>
            <th>Part Number</th>
            <th>Coste</th>
            <th>Características</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Pero me aparece el error en la consola:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

El json recibido es de la siguiente manera:

```
[{"id":1,"marca":"HP","modelo":"EliteBook 840","part_number":"44G57TH","coste":1,"caracteristicas":"4GB RAM 256GB SSD","created_at":"2017-04-16 14:36:58","updated_at":"2017-04-16 14:36:58"}]
```

Si le paso un ajax creado manualmente como el siguiente no tengo ningún problema y me muestra perfectamente los datos en mi tabla:

```
{
"data": [
{
    "marca": "Prueba",
    "modelo": "modelo",
    "part_number": "12354",
    "coste": "0",
    "caracteristicas": "Nose"
}]
```

}

La única diferencia que observo, es que el anterior no incluye "data:" y este sí, pero no sé como pasarlo de la misma manera.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola Sergio y [bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Una pregunta: ¿dóndes estás averiguando la longitud `length` de tus datos? actualiza tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

He encontrado la solución en otra pregunta de este foro:  [solución](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29568016/datatables-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined). Afectando a mi código de la siguiente manera:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#mytable').DataTable( {
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/modelo",
                "dataSrc": ""
                },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "marca" },
                { "data": "modelo" },
                { "data": "part_number" },
                { "data": "coste" },
                { "data": "caracteristicas" },
                {{--{ "data": "salary" }--}}
            ]
        } );
```

Espero os ayude. Gracias!